# Multiple Pages Minipage with Repeating Left Side

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to build something like this:

```
+---+------+
|   |      |
|   |      |
|   |      |
| l |  r   |
|   |      |
|   |      |
|   |      |
+---+------+
```

where `l`=left and `r`=right side of a page. The left side will always be the same (e.g. information about the author) whereas on the right side. My current approach with tcolorbox works nicely on a one-page document. However, if I want to add another page on the right side it becomes difficult because I want the left part to be the same on every page.
Any ideas?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

With `tcolorbox` you can define a `breakable` box with certain left margin which can be filled with repeated information in each fragment. Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mypage}[2][]{%
    empty,  
     notitle,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,
    parbox=false, 
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=.3\textwidth,
    right=5mm,
    top=4pt,
    breakable,
    pad at break*=0mm,
    vfill before first,
    overlay={%
        \node[rotate=90] at ([xshift=.15\textwidth]frame.west) {#2};
    },
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mypage}{Author information}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{mypage}

\end{document}
```